# When I was editing a question a comment was left from my username

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, review-queues

I was editing this question https://stackoverflow.com/review/helper/9797078 and when I click the save button, I saw that appears a comment from my user, but I don't make that comment, if you see the date (time) is the same date (time) of the edit question.

In addition, it is not possible to make a comment and edit a question at the same time.

This is the comment (that I don't write):

> javascript:void(0) –  Adrian Cid Almaguer 10 mins ago   edit

I edited the title in the question.

Comment: In the helper queue, the edit summary you give is added as a comment on the question. This is intended to be a way to explain to the OP why/how you edited their question, so they can better learn from the edit.

Comment: is javascript:void really what you put in the edit summary? seems rather uninformative.

Comment: @KevinB It really is- I double checked the edit before posting that, in case it really was a bug.

Comment: @Kendra I add aditionanl information to the my post

Comment: You should not be editing anything.

Comment: @GEOCHET I edit the title

Comment: @AdrianCidAlmaguer I think what Geochet means is that your post here was pretty much impossible to understand at first, and that English doesn't seem to be your first language, so editing might not be the best move here, as you are likely to make posts MORE complicated rather than less.

Comment: Didn't you clean the edit summary instead of typing something informative about your edit ? And to complete @GEOCHET remark, if you start editing a post, fix all which has to be fixed, look attentively to fix typos, etc. (FWIW I found both edits superfluous on a question which should be close as recommending a book/tool/library)

Comment: The issue with his editing is not that he didn't fix everything (that is a silly concept), but rather that his understanding of the language which he seeks to edit is very shaky.

Answer (score 7):

The relevant field on the Help and Improvement queue editor:

[image: Explain your edit in a comment]

Note the title: "Explain your edit in a **comment**". The text you type there should describe the purpose of your edit in a way that educates the author of the post in how to write better posts themselves; the intent is to reduce the number of lousy questions being written on Stack Overflow. You don't *have* to type anything there at all, but if you do... **Please write something meaningful.**

Also, please make edits that actually improve the questions you're editing; the edit you made just made the title longer without actually clarifying anything. When you make useful edits, it becomes a lot easier to write comments that are also useful...

Comment: This doesn't make it any less of a bug. Comments should be kept separate from edit summaries. But I guess complaining in your direction won't help so much anymore...